# TextView setText doesn't refresh the text

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, textview

In a `Fragment` I have this `Thread` that have to refresh the text of a 
`TextView`. The problem is that after `setText()` (the text is set in fact if I log `TextView.getText()` it returns the text changed) the screen the text is always the same. It change only if a add a view to the `Fragment`'s view.

This is the code,

```
Thread time = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                  TextView.setText("some text");
                  // i tried also to use TextView.invalidate()
                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `TextView` what's it? Is it a some singleton?

Comment: please post the full code.

Comment: The second, this loop is endless. Without any pause time. It's a bad code.

Comment: the code can't build, it's incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove while(true), you are blocking the UI thread with that